# Popup window confirmation/Preview records before Insertion happens

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap

Bear with my kindergarten introduction to Javascript and Phonegap.
I need a user to preview records captured before inserting them. Any work arounds? I have the implementation as follows:

```js
function Preview() {
  var vName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var vage = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var vplace = document.getElementById("place").value;

  var popup = window.open(view, 'Preview_records');
  popup.document.write('Name:' + vName + '<br /> Age:' + vage + '<br /> Place: ' + vplace + '<br />');
}
```

```html
<form id="view" method="POST" class="formular">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
  <label>age</label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" /><br>
  <label>place</label>
  <input type="text" name="place" id="place" />

  <button onclick="Preview()">Preview</button>
</form>
```

When this window pops up, I want to have PROCEED button and CANCEL Button, where PROCEED will take me to an insertion function and CANCEL will drop back to edit form data.

Insertion function as

```
        function Insertion() {
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(insertDT, errorZ, successY);
        }
```

Comment: @Sebastian Speitel, you only good at editing, no solutions? Wonder what changes you even made

Comment: Are you willing to display the to be inserted recorde on the same page or does it have to ba a new one. And if the second what backand language are you using?

Comment: @Sebastian Speitel  on the same page. Javascript. Am developing a phonegap mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something like this works in phonegap, but this would be my solution:

```js
function preview() {
  var vName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var vage = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var vplace = document.getElementById("place").value;

  var preview = document.getElementById("preview")
  preview.innerHTML = 'Name:' + vName + '<br /> Age:' + vage + '<br /> Place: ' + vplace + '<br />';
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  reset.style.display = "initial";
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit")
  submit.style.display = "initial";
  reset.onclick = () => {
    preview.innerHTML = "";
    reset.style.display = "none";
    submit.style.display = "none";
  };
}
```

```html
<form id="view" method="POST" class="formular">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
  <label>age</label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" /><br>
  <label>place</label>
  <input type="text" name="place" id="place" />

  <button onclick="preview()">Preview</button>
  <p id="preview"></p>
  <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Cancel" style="display:none">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Proceed" style="display:none">
</form>
```

Comment: The popup window isn't being generated

Comment: It's not a popup it just previews the input under the form. If you want it to be in a popup just change the code to fit.